# Get Id Field From Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want get id value from eloquent laravel and passing to variable to insert process. this is my eloquent to get data from siswa table

```
$siswa = Siswa::where('nis', $row['nis'])->first();
```

but when accessing id value like $siswa->id I'm getting error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DWKS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
if($siswa){
 $id=$siswa->id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$siswa variable can be null. Look at its contents with the `dd($siswa)` command.

To escape the error you can use it like this:

```
if($siswa)
{
 // $siswa not null.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can $id pass on your public function like

```
public function show($id)
{
    $siswa = Siswa::where('id', $id)->first();
 }
```

You can pass your id on your route

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to fix this.

1/ You can use `->firstOrFail()` to display a 404 page in case of your data is not found :

```
$siswa = Siswa::where('nis', $row['nis'])->firstOrFail();

// if $siswa is NULL, then it will display a 404 page, else it will continue
```

2/ You can add a simple condition to continue with your data :

```
$siswa = Siswa::where('nis', $row['nis'])->first();

if ($siswa) {
   // then continue 
}
```